# webpack module federation - how to load chunk of remote module

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am implementing MFE using @angular/architect module federation.

- I have remote modules (angular 13) that imports bundle of npm package in component. This npm package contains chunk files as well which cannot be imported as its dynamically generated.
- Package bundle is loaded and is part of build - but chunks are not available due to path searching at remote module level and not from node_modules.
- I tried to copy chunks manually using angular.json's assets array, this works on local

But when i try to load remote module in shell, chunks are not available. Module tries to load those chunks from shell level.

**Possible option ** : I can host npm package to CDN that helps loading chunks using publicPath
But this is not a proper fix - i have many npm packages generating chunks.

**Options tried**

- Tried publicPath in output of npm package. But its not helping. It seems publicPath works when main bundle is loaded in script tag and not with import
- Tried DynamicPulicPathPlugin - but no help
- document.currentScript is null because npm package's bundle is imported in component and not loaded via script tag

Here are some crucial details

**Webpack's output config** of my NPM package

```
module.exports = () => {
output: { 
  filename: basePackageJson.name + '.bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  chunkFilename: ('pdf-service-chunk/[chunkhash].bundle.js'),
  library: 'pdfService',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  publicPath:'auto'
 }
}
```

Webpack of remote module

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "ueRemoteUiModule",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },

      // For remotes (please adjust)
      name: "ueRemoteUiModule",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        'ueRemoteUiModule': './/src/modules/remote.module.ts'
      },

      // For hosts (please adjust)
      // remotes: {
      //     "mfe1": "http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",

      // },

      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        "@angular/platform-browser": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
      })
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
    new DynamicPublicPathPlugin()
  ],
};
```

angular.json of remote module

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets-tc",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/pdf-service/pdf-service-chunk/",
    "output": "./pdf-service-chunk/"
  }
],
```

Routing in host/Shell using loadRemoteModule method of @angular-architect/module-federation

```
{
    path: 'reservation', loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:5900/remoteEntry.js',
      exposedModule: 'UeRemoteUiModule'
    })
      .then(m => m.UeRemoteModule)
  },
```